# Weighted degree centrality

Tags: graph-theory, python, network

I have a conceptual question about graphs which I couldn't find the answer to. I am calculating some node centralities and using them as features for a machine learning problem. I am using Networkx python library.

I noticed that for the [degree centrality](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.degree_centrality.html) the library does the weighting of the values by the highest possible number of connections. In other words, the degree centrality of a node is defined by the number of connections the node has divided by the number of nodes in the graph minus one.

Although, from graph theory literature, the degree centrality of a node is simply counting the number of edges a node has. As far as I understand.

I wonder what is the implications of this weighting of the values by the library? Doesn't it completely changes the concept of the degree centrality?

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't it completely changes the concept of the degree centrality?

Well, no. As long as you operate on one graph, nothing really changes. From what I understand you are asking why the library implementation is inconsistent with the literature. The library itself provides a good answer:

> The degree centrality values are **normalized** by dividing by the maximum
> possible degree in a simple graph n-1 where n is the number of nodes in G.

So if you just want the vertex degree, use `G.degree`. If you want to normalize this number by the size of the graph (which is arguably more useful) use `degree_centrality(G)`.

Comment: But isn't this normalization interfering, or changing the method? Because the normalization is based on the total number of nodes in the graph. For example, if we only count the number of edges and normalize based on max and min degrees, we would have a different normalization. Right?

Comment: Normalizing on the basis of maximum and minimum vertices would not make much sense -- individual oddities could completely corrupt the method. *Degree centrality* is a measure of how well connected a vertex is to others. When comparing different networks (and I guess that's the idea behind NetworkX) it's a good thing to compare them as fractions (or perhaps percentages of the total) rather than as single numbers that depend significantly on the total number of vertices.